# Datastore entity key collision

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In development I have an empty datastore.
Online I have a datastore with millions of entities.

In the development datastore (locally) I put one new entity (generating a new key).
Then I export the entity and put it in the online datastore (with the key generated locally). What is the risk that the key generated locally to have already been assigned to an entity in the online datastore?

Or would it be simpler to avoid collision by creating the keys locally like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(kind, new Date() + i);
    // continue to creating and inserting entities...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities:

> Instead of using key name strings or generating numeric IDs
>   automatically, advanced applications may sometimes wish to assign
>   their own numeric IDs manually to the entities they create. Be aware,
>   however, that there is nothing to prevent the Datastore from assigning
>   one of your manual numeric IDs to another entity. The only way to
>   avoid such conflicts is to have your application obtain a block of IDs
>   with the methods DatastoreService.allocateIds() or
>   AsyncDatastoreService.allocateIds(). The Datastore's automatic ID
>   generator will keep track of IDs that have been allocated with these
>   methods and will avoid reusing them for another entity, so you can
>   safely use such IDs without conflict.

You must either generate **all** of the numeric keys manually (and in such a way that they will never collide) or use `allocateIds()`. There is specifically no guarantee that anything you generate manually will not collide with an existing key, unless you use that function. The generated key ids are not like an auto increment field in a relational db which increment by one each time.

Comment: I understand, but here we are talking about putting the entities (hence creating the keys) in the local datastore in development mode, then exporting them to the production online datastore, so it would seem to me that the only way to prevent collision in this case is to create the keys using some sort of time-related ids/names.

Comment: That will only work if you generate 100% of your entity keys in that way (i.e., do exactly 0 puts without ids), and do it with such time resolution that zero duplicates will be created. If you already have 1 entity created in the normal way, it could fail.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the kind of IDs you have on the entity. If they are integers, they are small and you can easily have conflicts.

I would suggest just creating a slightly different key format from what Google uses by default. Your function above looks like it should work as long as the KeyFactory uses the full accuracy of the clock (i.e. does not stop at seconds).

Comment: I never set any ID of any key. They are all standard, automatically assigned when I first put the Entity. In virtual relationships, I use KeyFactory.keyToString().

Comment: All entities are created using `new Entity(kind)`

Answer (score 0):

When the datastore generates keys the ids are **integers**. If you generate keys using **Strings** as Ids then they will not override the existing entities.

```
a.key.id() == 1
b.key.id() == '1'
a.key.id() != b.key.id()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a bit more information about your use case for anyone to suggest a proper solution. You could for instance create keys on the dev database like this:

```
  KeyFactory.createKey(entity, "dev_" + UUID.randomUUID())
```

Another option would be to create a small utility or app that will retrieve the Entity from the local database and then POST it to the development database. The online server getting the POST would create a new Entity and assign all properties from the client except the key, thereby letting GAE generate a new key automatically. The new key could then be sent back to the client, as a response to the POST operation.

Again, I don't know if you later want to update the local database an resync with the online, but if so, the first approach with defining your own key would work as the next sync will update the entity online.